# Using JPackage on modular application without JLink?

Tags: maven, jlink, jpackage

I'm trying to create an installer for my application using JPackage. My understanding is that JPackage takes two inputs: your Java application and a Java runtime. Now, if your application is modular, you typically generate a custom Java runtime using `jlink`. However, I'm having trouble getting jlink to work because one of my dependencies is an automatic module and I'd have to generate an explicit module declaration first.

As a shortcut, is there a way to run JPackage without jlink for a modular application? My goal here is to create an installer/executable, even if it's not the smallest in size. Can I pass the full JRE as an input?
What are my options here? Thank you!